# HTX / Huobi error api-signature-not-valid

Tags: cryptography, postman, huobi

Have a problem with HTX api. I can't succeed any request. Have

```
"err-code": "api-signature-not-valid",
"err-msg": "Signature not valid: Verification failure [校验失败]"
```

every time.

I try to get back my orders through POSTMAN.

[image: I prepare signature]

Then, I URL encode signature.

[image: Then, I paste signature in POSTMAN]

Every time have:

```json
{
    "status": "error",
    "err-code": "api-signature-not-valid",
    "err-msg": "Signature not valid: Verification failure [校验失败]",
    "data": null
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What about those newlines (\n)? They're appear to be in the form you used to compute the HMAC but they're not in the actual URL you are using. That will result in a mismatch

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i just follow the API doc. https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#authentication point 6,7,8

Comment: ok, that was useful. I don't know what tool you are using to compute the HMAC, it looks like it might be an online site. Are you actually entering newline characters, or are you typing the two characters `\n`? It looks like you are typing the characters which would be wrong. If you could provide an example using a fake secret key then the calculation could be checked.

Comment: You rock! for signature, it just be new line without \n. Documentation trap me... Thank you so much !